# Add custome column in PrimeNG exprot as CSV

Tags: javascript, angular, csv, primeng

I want to add some custom columns in the PrimeNG table, could you please guide me, that how we can add some other field in export CSV but that column is not added in my `Dashboard` table.

Answer (score 0):

There is a sample code that saves the table by column 
as a base I used original prime ng implementation method exportCSV({selectionOnly:true}) (export selected row)

For full demo see https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-table-ecport-by-column

the key method is exportCSV

```
exportCSV(table: Table){
    var _this = this;
    var selColumns = this.selectedColumns;
    var csv = '';
    var exportFilename = 'download';
    var csvSeparator = ',';
    //headers
        for (var i = 0; i < selColumns.length; i++) {
            var column = selColumns[i];
            if (column.exportable !== false && column.field) {
                csv += '"' + (column.header || column.field) + '"';
                if (i < (selColumns.length - 1)) {
                    csv += csvSeparator;
                }
            }
        }
        //body
        this.carsData.forEach(function (record, i) {
            csv += '\n';

                for (var i_1 = 0; i_1 < table.columns.length; i_1++) {
                const column = table.columns[i_1]; 
                var showColumn = selColumns.find(x=> column.field === x.field);

                if (column.exportable !== false && column.field && showColumn != null) {
                    // var cellData = JSON.stringify(record, column.field);
                     var cellData;
                     Object.keys(record).forEach(key =>{
                       if(key === column.field){
                         cellData = record[key];
                       }
                         })

                    //  console.log(cellData);
                    if (cellData != null) {
                        if (table.exportFunction) {
                            cellData = table.exportFunction({
                                data: cellData,
                                field: column.field
                            });
                        }
                        else
                            cellData = String(cellData).replace(/"/g, '""');
                    }
                    else
                        cellData = '';
                    csv += '"' + cellData + '"';
                    if (i_1 < (table.columns.length - 1)) {
                        csv += csvSeparator;
                    }
                }
            }

        });
        var blob = new Blob([csv], {
            type: 'text/csv;charset=utf-8;'
        });
        if (window.navigator.msSaveOrOpenBlob) {
            navigator.msSaveOrOpenBlob(blob, exportFilename + '.csv');
        }
        else {
            var link = document.createElement("a");
            link.style.display = 'none';
            document.body.appendChild(link);
            if (link.download !== undefined) {
                link.setAttribute('href', URL.createObjectURL(blob));
                link.setAttribute('download', exportFilename + '.csv');
                link.click();
            }
            else {
                csv = 'data:text/csv;charset=utf-8,' + csv;
                window.open(encodeURI(csv));
            }
            document.body.removeChild(link);
        }
 }
```